Is there any way to make MudAutocomplete have virtualization functionality?
I made MudSelect virtualizable by wrapping MudSelectItem with Virtualize from Blazor but I can't do the same with MudAutoComplete, while MudAutocomplete is much more intuitive than MudSelect. Is there any way to make MudAutocomple virtualizable? Example of how I virtualize MudSelect:
<div style="height:45px;overflow-y:hidden;padding-top:2px">
        <MudSelect @bind-SelectedValues=@UserSelectedId Label="User" T="string">
            <Virtualize Items="UserList">
                <MudSelectItem Value="@context.Id">@context.Id - @context.Name</MudSelectItem>
            </Virtualize>
        </MudSelect> 
</div>


I don't think there's a way to virtualize it. Why would you choose MudAutocomplete over MudSelect?

@Uerschel Because MudSelect has no way to enter keywords to search. With a list of over 100, how long will the user have to scroll to find what they want to select?

That's a valid reason. But I guess you would still like the user to be able scroll through it, right? CodeBeamOrg provides various extensions to multiple mudblazor components, even one for the select. https://codebeam-mudextensions.pages.dev/mudselectextended
It has a search function aswell

I will think about using it. Thank you for your suggestion.
